# MAXON Escon Motor Controller ROS

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a mobile robot platform running with 4 Escon 50/5 drivers an 4 DCX motors. I have created my motor controllers .edc file via escon software; but I couldn't find a way to communicate with ROS to control motor drivers. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386430/maxon-escon-motor-controller-ros/) by [mergen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33082/mergen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@mergen Take a look at this ROS library: http://wiki.ros.org/epos_hardware

There is some additional information about the motors you are looking in their repo, or you may be able to find someone that has more info: https://github.com/RIVeR-Lab/epos_hardware/issues/26

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1